# MySQL JOIN with where clause and group by count

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by

I run a the following query,

```
SELECT status.status_id, status.status_name, COUNT(workbin.status_id)
FROM `status`
LEFT JOIN `workbin` ON workbin.status_id = status.status_id
GROUP BY status.status_id
```

and got the output

```
status_id status_name count
1   New              44
2   On Hold          1
3   In Analysis      2
4   In Development   12
5   In Testing       17
6   In Release       2
7   Completed        151
8   In Review        0
9   Unit Testing     0
11  Rework           0
12  Reopen           0
```

Now i need to add a where clause in this query, to retrive the data based on the user id in the `workbin` table. So the result will show only the count for the user. The user id is also stored in the `workbin` table.

If i add a where clause `WHERE`workbin`.`task_assigned_id`= 37`
and found few status_id and status_name are missing(which have the 0 value).
But i need all the status counts for the task assigned user(workbin.task_assigned_id).

Comment: I recommend spending time on sql tutorial sites to start. This is not one.

Comment: @Drew I think it's the place for asking questions when someone can't find solutions after trying himself, which the OP is doing here. Try to understand the question and you will know where he is stuck with.

Comment: ok fair enuf. btw add something to your group by clause

Comment: @Drew check my answer! :)

Comment: I did, I was chatting to you :P

Comment: Oh! Sorry, you asked about adding `status.status_name` also in the GROUP BY ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98998/discussion-between-tareq-mahmood-and-drew).

Comment: @Drew You are welcome to edit my answer, if you find something useful. (Anyways, pls remove the downvote here if you were the one! It doesn't seem fair to me! :P)

Comment: @TareqMahmood I am one of 20 people that have come to this question so far. Some upvote, some downvote. I tend to not assume who did what. That will drive ya crazy if you do

Comment: @Drew Haha! Sorry! ;)

Comment: @TareqMahmood thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because by `WHERE` clause, you are specifying to show only the records which have a value `task_assigned_id = 37` in `workbin` table. So, you cannot get the rows, for which you don't have a row in `workbin` table (even though it is in `status` table.) The solution can be something like this, to keep the conditions of your `WHERE` clause in `LEFT JOIN` part:

```
SELECT status.status_id, status.status_name, COUNT(workbin.status_id)
FROM `status`
LEFT JOIN `workbin` ON workbin.status_id = status.status_id AND workbin.task_assigned_id= 37
GROUP BY status.status_id
```